# pyttsx3 wait to finish?

Tags: python, pyttsx3

im using pyttsx3 for my telegram bot. i have this code.

```
def TTSBot(message):
    print("TTS")
    Engine.save_to_file(message.text, "Voice.mp3")
    Engine.runAndWait()
    FBot.send_audio(message.chat.id, open("Voice.mp3", "rb"), reply_to_message_id=message.id)
    print("done")
```

this executes when the command is called but it sends the previous command. it dosnt wait for Engine to finish it's work. how do i make it wait?

i tried using Engine.runAndWain() inside the send_audio bot it dosnt return the Voice file.

also if you know a way to not save the file and just directly input it into the commands let me know.

Answer (score 0):

*Please specify your operating system next time you deal with audio in case you are on linux and you simply need to install a few packages to fix this.*

Now, the problem you requested is not regarding pyttsx3 but regarding `FBot`.
I assume you are using [python-telegram bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot) because the API looks alike. Within its [docs](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_audio) the function `bot.send_audio` is `async` which means you must mark your function as asynchronous to `await` the function `FBot.send_audio()`.
You can, of course, put the event loop inside `TTSBot()` but it's better to put it in their caller.

This is the complete code for reference.

```py
import asyncio
# import other libraries

# other code

async def TTSBot(message):
    # print("TTS") (it is not advised to put simple messages like this, instead use a logger)
    Engine.save_to_file(message.text, "Voice.mp3")
    Engine.runAndWait()
    await FBot.send_audio(message.chat.id, open("Voice.mp3", "rb"), reply_to_message_id=message.id)
    #print("done") (it is not advised to put simple messages like this, instead use a logger)

def caller(): # put real function
    # other code
    asyncio.run(TTSBot(msg))
    # if you are using Python3.6 or lower, comment the previous line and uncomment the following lines
    # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.run_until_complete(TTSBot(msg))
    # loop.close()
    # other code
```

## **UPDATE**

Since you are using [pytelegrambotapi](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/), in its [documention](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.send_audio) the audio file shall not be of type `str` but of type [`telebot.types.InputFile`](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.InputFile). Thus, you must pass it using that class.

```py
def TTSBot(message):
    Engine.save_to_file(message.text, "Voice.mp3")
    Engine.runAndWait()
    FBot.send_audio(message.chat.id, InputFile("Voice.mp3"), reply_to_message_id=message.id)
```

And there's no need to modify the caller now.

Also I don't know how your caller works but I'd also like to give you a note that the function `send_audio` returns the [`message`](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.Message).

Comment: im using pytelegrambot for my bot. i did this and im getting TypeError: object Message can't be used in 'await' expression error.

Comment: I do not find that in PYPI. Please provide a link.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/0.3.0/

Comment: If you are using V0.3.0, update to V4.9.0. The following response (check update section of my answer) will be based on version 4.9.0.

Comment: the issue still presists. im still getting the prevoius answer instead of the current one.